# What does $df=g(x)dx$ mean?

Tags: calculus, definition, differential

I understand this $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=g(x)$, since $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$ has precise definition (I guess you know the definition, so I skip it.)

but what is the definition of this $df=g(x)dx$. I can "somehow" understand what it means. but does it exist a precise definition for this notation?

Thank you.

Comment: We can find a precise definition of the *differential* into: Vladimir Zorich, [Mathematical Analysis I](https://books.google.it/books?id=rxOoCwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Springer (2nd ed 2016), page 177.

Comment: Unless you are dealing with differential forms, it is an awful notation that seems to permeate teaching in high schools. It is suggestive of the idea that $f(x+h)-f(x) \approx g(x) h$ (which can be properly formalised).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I view $df = g(x) dx$ as a mnemonic: it's formally equivalent to $\frac{df}{dx} = g(x)$, but it's written in such a way as to allow you to perform substitution of variables when integrating, i.e.
$$\int_{x=\dots}^{x=\dots} (\quad\dots\quad)\; \underline{g(x)\; dx} = \int_{f=\dots}^{f=\dots} (\quad\dots\quad)\;\; \underline{df},$$
and if you think of "df" and "dx" as "a small change in f" and "a small change in x" respectively, it helps you remember how the proof goes.

Answer (score 3):

It is an abuse of notation, much loved especially by physicists, that means:
$$
\frac{df}{dx}=g(x)
$$

Comment: According to John Olmsted in his book Advanced Calculus, if we view $dx$ as a real number, and if $y=f(x)$, then $dy$ is a function of the independent variables $x$ and $dx$ and can be defined by $dy=f'(x)\,dx$

Answer (score 2):

In Olmsted's Advanced Calculus, the author begins with a differentiable function $y=f(x)$ of $x$ and introduced two symbols, $dx$ and $dy$.

If we interpret $dx$ to be an arbitrary real number, then $dy=d(f(x))$ can be defined as function of the two independent variables $x$ and $dx$ given by

$$dy(x,dx)=f'(x)\,dx\tag 1$$

The differentials $dx$ and $dy$, as related by $(1)$, have and obvious geometric interpretation.  The equation of tangent line to the curve $y=f(x)$ at $x_0$ can be written $y=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+f(x_0)$.  Then, if we change $x$ to $x+dx$, the change in $y$ is $f'(x_0)dx$, which is precisely $dy(x_0,dx)$.

Answer (score 1):

The second is called [differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function) if $g(x)=f'(x)$ and represent the principal part of the change of $f(x)$ with respect to changes of $x$.